# Spring webhook endpoint get entire body as well as pojo

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, paypal

I am making an application using spring, and I have a webhook endpoint as shown below

```kotlin
    @PostMapping("/paypal")
    fun paypalMapping(
        @RequestHeader headers: Map<String, String>,
        @RequestBody paypalOrder: PaypalOrder
    ) {
    // Stuff in here
    }
```

Now, the problem I have with this is the paypal `Event.validateReceivedEvent` requires the entire webhook body as a string, and as you can see above, I map it to a POJO I made, meaning I do not have the entire webhook body as a string. I tried simply adding another `@RequestBody body:String` parameter to the method, and that just came with an error about not being able to find the body.

Thanks

Comment: If you need the entire body (to check a signature?), you'll probably have to pass it as the string and map it yourself manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind the request body twice unfortunately, you can only use the `@RequestBody` once. What I'd do is to bind it as a `String` and deserialize manually:

```kotlin
@PostMapping("/paypal")
fun paypalMapping(
    @RequestHeader headers: Map<String, String>,
    @RequestBody body: String
) {
    // Stuff in here
}
```